# Python Selenium - WebDriverException: browsingContextFn() .currentWindowGlobal is null

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, instagram

I wrote an Instagram bot with Python and Selenium, which works just fine. Most of the time.

Sometimes, in save data when it should click "don't save," its randomly throws this error:

```
WebDriverException: browsingContextFn() .currentWindowGlobal is null
```

When I restart the program, it just works fine.

My question is: what does this error mean and how can I fix it? I tried to search this but found nothing.

I can post my code if really needed but I'm not that good at coding and it's a little messy.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Posting some code will definitely make it easier to answer your question. If it's messy, please distill it into a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).